# How to define a javascript property that can have multiple form?

Tags: javascript

For Example the IE Tabular Control can be used as follow

```
recordset.fields(i).name;
recordset.fields.count;
```

How can I use javascript to define the fields property ?

when I define

```
this.fields = new FieldObject();
this.fields = function( index ) {
   .....
}
```

but it can only recognize the last define.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions in javascript are objects. They can have key-value pairs added to them like standard objects can. In the first example, your code is calling a function `fields(i)` that returns an object with the `name` property. In the second example, the property `count` being access on the function `fields`:

```js
const obj = {
  fields: function() {
    return {name: "foo"};
  }
}

obj.fields.count = 1;
console.log(obj.fields().name);
console.log(obj.fields.count);
```

Above we're adding the property `count` to the `fields` function.

You can add multiple properties to the fields function by using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), which will merge the (enumerable own) properties from one object with another:

```
this.fields = function( index ) {
  return {name: "foo"};
}
Object.assign(this.fields, new FieldObject());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function recordset_field(){
//properties
this.name = '',
this.blabla = 123,

//method
this.action1 = function(){
//do action
//get property value
console.log(this.name);
},
};

//instance
recordset.fields = array();
recordset.fields.push(new recordset_field());

//access and use
recordset.fields[0].name = "123";
recordset.fields[0].action1();
```